# LINQ join with flattened result (SelectMany?)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table of items and table of item types, related by item type ID.  I have the query expression below (despite the fact that I much prefer the chained syntax but I can't figure it out for this one).

```
var items = (from i in _context.Items
       join it in _context.ItemTypes on i.ItemTypeId equals it.ItemTypeId
       select new { i, ItemCategory = it.ItemCategory, ItemTypeName = it.ItemTypeName }).AsQueryable();
```

The resulting JSON looks something like this

```
data: [
{
    i: {
        itemId: 72,
        itemTypeId: 8,
    },
    itemCategory: "Book",
    itemTypeName: "Book"
    }
]
```

But I would prefer this instead

```
data: [
{
    itemId: 72,
    itemTypeId: 8,
    itemCategory: "Book",
    itemTypeName: "Book"
}
]
```

I know that I can do it by select new { field1, field2 } but I have a ton of fields and really don't feel like messing with that each time I need to.

So my questions are 1. How can I accomplish this? and 2. Could it be done with the chained method syntax instead?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if there is are no items in i or more than 1.

Comment: How would you avoid duplicate fields? Explicitly selecting them makes sure the compiler detects those. For example: What if `i` contains a field called `itemCategory`?

Comment: Fair enough.  Obviously both contain ItemTypeId.  So I'd like to do (SQL equivalent...) i.* and then it.fieldA, it.fieldB, it.fieldC manually.  It's a M:1 relationship so there's only one item type per item.

Comment: There is no C# syntax for this. Doing it programmatically, your main issue is you have to create an anonymous type at runtime, which is quite a bit of code (see [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), though I have a simplified version that uses fields instead of properties). Your best bet may be to flatten the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using EF and there is a relation between to tables, then you need to do sit like:

```
var items = _context.Items.Include(x => x.ItemType)
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                ItemId = x.Id,
                ItemTypeId = x.ItemTypeId,
                ItemCategory = x.ItemCategory,
                ItemTypeName = x.ItemType.Name
            });
```

if there is no relation between the two lists:

```
var result = items.Join(itemTypes,
                        itm => itm.ItemTypeId,
                        type => type.Id,
                        (itm, type) => new
                         {
                               ItemId = itm.Id,
                               ItemTypeId = itm.ItemTypeId,
                               ItemCategory = itm.ItemCategory,
                               ItemTypeName = type.ItemType.Name
                         });
```

Comment: The OP also wants the flattened result of `i`.

Comment: @Silvermind if you take a look at question this not actually something that needs flattening, my code already accomplishes what he has mentioned as example.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I'm trying to avoid manually listing out all of the fields like that.  I'd love to return (SQL equivalent...) i.* and it.*

Comment: but you one some selective fields from 2 different lists, it can't magically happen unless you name them.

Comment: Right.  So 
```new {i, someUniqueName = it.theduplicatedfieldname}```
should work.  Given that, is there no way to flatten that list to all fall in the same JSON object?

Comment: @mateoc15 nope I'm afraid not

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I know how it works. I'm merely repeating the question. I'm specifically referring to _I know that I can do it by select new { field1, field2 } but I have a ton of fields_

Comment: well I thought it would be nice to show how the chaining is done and also mention EF.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani That **is** nice ;), but the most complex task was left out. Or you could explain why it is a bad idea.